# Why does java.lang.NullPointerException appear during testing controller?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

my code:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class,})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AtiActHasFormControllerTest {

    
    MockMvc mvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private AtiServiceImpl atiServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
     
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
    }

    private List<ActHasForm> getActHasForm() {

        RegulatoryAct newoneRegulatoryAct = new RegulatoryAct(1, "4927-У", new Date(2018 - 01 - 10),
                "О перечне, формах и порядке составления и представления форм",
                "указание регулирует составление отчетности");
        RegulatoryForm newoneRegulatoryForm = new RegulatoryForm(1, "0403202",
                "Сведения об оценке выполнения операторами", "форма ДИБ (нерегулярная)", new Date(2019 - 03 - 30),
                new Date(2022 - 12 - 12), new Date(2012 - 01 - 13));

        RegulatoryAct newtwoRegulatoryAct = new RegulatoryAct(1, "4847-У", new Date(2018 - 01 - 11),
                "О ВНЕСЕНИИ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ В УКАЗАНИЕ ", "регулирует составления отчетности");
        RegulatoryForm newtwoRegulatoryForm = new RegulatoryForm(1, "0403582", "Сведения о событиях,",
                "Форма ДИБ (Квартальна", new Date(2019 - 03 - 23), new Date(2023 - 01 - 12), new Date(2022 - 12 - 12));

        ActHasForm oneActHasForm = new ActHasForm(1, newoneRegulatoryAct, newoneRegulatoryForm, "Новая редакция формы");
        ActHasForm twoActHasForm = new ActHasForm(1, newtwoRegulatoryAct, newtwoRegulatoryForm, "Новая редакция формы");
        return List.of(oneActHasForm, twoActHasForm);

    }
    @Test
    void findAllActHasForm() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(this.atiServiceImpl.findAllActHasForm()).thenReturn(getActHasForm());
         mvc.perform(get("/acthasform/"))
                 .andExpect(status().isOk())
                 .andExpect(view().name("acthasform/list"))
                 .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/resuorses/templates/acthasform/list.html"))
                 .andExpect(model().attribute("acthasform", hasSize(2)))
                 .andExpect(model().attribute("acthasform", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                                    hasProperty("actId", is("4927-У")),
                                    hasProperty("formId", is("0403202"))
                            )
                    )))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("id", is(2L)),
                                    hasProperty("actId", is("4847-У")),
                                    hasProperty("formId", is("0403582"))
                            )
                    )));
         verify(atiServiceImpl, times(1)).findAllActHasForm();
         verifyNoMoreInteractions(atiServiceImpl);            
    }
}
```

when testing, it gives an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ru.se_nata.ati.service.AtiServiceImpl.findAllActHasForm()" because "this.atiServiceImpl" is null
    at ru.se_nata.ati.controller.AtiActHasFormControllerTest.findAllActHasForm(AtiActHasFormControllerTest.java:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my testing code?

Comment: What is the import for `@Test`?

Comment: @Lesiak for Test import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

Comment: Because you are mxing JUnit4 and JUnit5. `@RuNWith` is for JUnit4, your `@Test` is for JUnit5.  Either change your test to fully be JUnit5 or JUnit4 but don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your test:

**Problem1: mixing jUnit4 and jUnit5**

- `@Test` comes from jUnit5
- `@Before` comes from jUnit4
- `@RunWith` comes from jUnit4

Your test is run under jUnit5, `@Before` and `@RunWith` are ignored, thus you get NPE

**Problem 2: incorrect usage of mocks**

You call `Mockito.when` on an object which is not a mock.

**Solution**

For your test, I would suggest using `@WebMvcTest` which only initializes web layer of the app.

See [Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Something along the lines of:

```java
@WebMvcTest(YOUR_CONTROLLER.class)
public class AtiActHasFormControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private AtiServiceImpl atiServiceImpl;

    private List<ActHasForm> getActHasForm() {

        RegulatoryAct newoneRegulatoryAct = new RegulatoryAct(1, "4927-У", new Date(2018 - 01 - 10),
                "О перечне, формах и порядке составления и представления форм",
                "указание регулирует составление отчетности");
        RegulatoryForm newoneRegulatoryForm = new RegulatoryForm(1, "0403202",
                "Сведения об оценке выполнения операторами", "форма ДИБ (нерегулярная)", new Date(2019 - 03 - 30),
                new Date(2022 - 12 - 12), new Date(2012 - 01 - 13));

        RegulatoryAct newtwoRegulatoryAct = new RegulatoryAct(1, "4847-У", new Date(2018 - 01 - 11),
                "О ВНЕСЕНИИ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ В УКАЗАНИЕ ", "регулирует составления отчетности");
        RegulatoryForm newtwoRegulatoryForm = new RegulatoryForm(1, "0403582", "Сведения о событиях,",
                "Форма ДИБ (Квартальна", new Date(2019 - 03 - 23), new Date(2023 - 01 - 12), new Date(2022 - 12 - 12));

        ActHasForm oneActHasForm = new ActHasForm(1, newoneRegulatoryAct, newoneRegulatoryForm, "Новая редакция формы");
        ActHasForm twoActHasForm = new ActHasForm(1, newtwoRegulatoryAct, newtwoRegulatoryForm, "Новая редакция формы");
        return List.of(oneActHasForm, twoActHasForm);

    }

    @Test
    void findAllActHasForm() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(this.atiServiceImpl.findAllActHasForm()).thenReturn(getActHasForm());
         mvc.perform(get("/acthasform/"))
                 .andExpect(status().isOk())
                 .andExpect(view().name("acthasform/list"))
                 .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/resuorses/templates/acthasform/list.html"))
                 .andExpect(model().attribute("acthasform", hasSize(2)))
                 .andExpect(model().attribute("acthasform", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                                    hasProperty("actId", is("4927-У")),
                                    hasProperty("formId", is("0403202"))
                            )
                    )))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                            allOf(
                                    hasProperty("id", is(2L)),
                                    hasProperty("actId", is("4847-У")),
                                    hasProperty("formId", is("0403582"))
                            )
                    )));
         verify(atiServiceImpl, times(1)).findAllActHasForm();
         verifyNoMoreInteractions(atiServiceImpl);            
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to fix it, but now it gives a different stack of errors : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@792b9dd3 testClass = ru.se_nata.ati.AtiApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [ru.se_nata.ati.AtiApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers

Comment: Probably your controller has dependencies on other services which are not part of the web layer. I cannot really tell without full stack trace.